# How to count the amount of digits in an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to count the amount of numbers in an input for example in the four digit number 4256 how would I find out how many fours, twos, fives and sixes there are. I would be looking for the amount of numbers in a random number.
EDIT: 
I continued to work on this and this is what I got. Apologies for asking a duplicate question.
import random

```
import random

guess = random.randint(1000,9999)
guess = str(guess)
correct = 0

print(guess) #this was only here for testing

number = input("Enter ")
list(number)

if number[0] in guess:
    correct = correct + 1
    print (correct)
```

Comment: There several different ways to do what your asking. Could you please show what _you_ have tried though?

Comment: looking for a duplicate...

Comment: `collections.Counter(input())`?

Answer (score -1):

To count how many times x appears in y, use

z = y.count(x)